# adding secondry y-axis in python line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add secondary y-axis. I have my data in CSV with three column date, lscc and cc. I want to add LSCC as first y-axis and CC as secondry. so far I have done this

```
df=pd.read_csv("E29Lsccvalue.csv", index_col='Date' )
plt.ylabel("")
plt.xlabel("Low level Similarity Class Cohesion (LSCC) Evolution")
df.plot(kind="line", marker='o',legend=None)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

thanks

Comment: Try reading the answers in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Although no reproducible date is provided, I guess you can achieve the desired result by doing this:

```
ax = df.plot(secondary_y='CC')
```

eventually adding all your `ax` customization required

**edit**: dotted line customization

Suppose you need a dotted vertical line at a certain position on your x-axis (in this example, at position 2 from your pandas index), use [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html) and `':'` as linestyle (dots)

```
ax = a.plot(secondary_y='Price')
ax.axvline(a.index.values[2], linestyle=':')
```

Comment: hey thanks alot. one more question how can i add a dotted line on a specific date?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: hey thanks I have tried the solution for dotted line but the thing is my x-axis is date and axvline isnt accepting the date value

Comment: axvline accepts a position, not a value!

Comment: but its nt accepting the position im specifying. Im doing it like this                                                  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv("E29Lsccvalue.csv")
axes1 =df.plot(kind="line", marker="o", legend=None,secondary_y='CC',figsize=(6,6),rot=90)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Low level Similarity Class Cohesion (LSCC)")
axes1.set_ylabel("Class Cohesion(CC)")
line=df.iloc[20][0]
print(line)
axes1.axvline(line, linestyle=':', color='r')
plt.show()

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you did, but it seems like your `line` is again a value and not the index position on the x-axis. 
`iloc` is returning the 20th element and you are accessing the first value with [0]...try `df.index.values[20]` instead

Comment: I tried that but it dnt show a dotted line I tried to print this index value and im getting the date but its not visible on graph

Comment: why don't you open a new post with some code example so that it's easier to address that specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

Within matplotlib I have used `twinx()` when I want to utilize the existing X-axis I have created, yet plot more data on top with a different Y axis. In your case with `df` as the first plot object:

```
axCC = df.twinx() # second axis sharing the same X axis of the original
```

Then you can include plots, labels, and other parameters referenced to this axis through calls such as:

```
axCC.set_ylabel("ExampleLabel",color="tab:red")
axCC.plot(xData,yData,color="blue")
```

Etc, etc.

A fully functional example with more detail is shown [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html)